# Counting with replacement with mixed concepts

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

A quick doubt. Consider the two following questions:

1. How many ways are there to put 7 indistinguishable balls into 4 boxes in a row?
2. How many ways are there to put 7 indistinguishable balls into 4 distinguishable boxes?

While the first is simply $\binom{7+4-1}{7}$, the second I would guess it would be $\binom{7+4-1}{7}\times4!$. However, in [here](http://www.elcamino.edu/faculty/gfry/210/DistributeBallsBoxes.pdf), it says that the answer is still $\binom{7+4-1}{7}$ (Theorem 4).

Which is the right answer? Did I miss something?

Comment: Well, what is the reasoning behind your guess? Why do you think there are more different ways to put balls in "distinguishable boxes" than in "boxes in a row"?

Comment: Because for example the configuration (7,0,0,0) should be different compared to (0,7,0,0), because although it's the same in ball terms, one is a permutation of box 1 with another box (for example), and the other could be box 2 with 7 balls, which make the two things different.

Comment: Yes. But this is so in both cases? Saying that the boxes are in a row means that they are distinguishable ("first", "second", "third", and "last" box). The only difference between 1. and 2. is that 2. doesn't say what the distinguishing factor between the boxes is (ordering, color, shape,..)

Comment: Oh, and ${7+4-1}\choose 7$ gives you the number of possibilities for the case that you *can* distinguish between the boxes.